# reload tableview after call to WCF service

Tags: ios5, uitableview, xcode4.3, sudzc

I am calling a WCF service to display data in a UITableViewController.The code in the .m file is:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  [docTable setDataSource:self];
  [docTable setDelegate:self];
}

-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    EDViPadDocSyncService *service = [[EDViPadDocSyncService alloc]init];
    EDVCategory *cat = [EDVCategory alloc];
    cat.categoryId = [catId intValue];
    [service getDocsByCatId:self action:@selector(getDocsByCatIdHandler:) category:cat];
    [docTable reloadData];
}

- (void) getDocsByCatIdHandler: (id)value 
{
if([value isKindOfClass:[NSError class]]) 
    {
    NSLog(@"%@", value);
    return;
}
if([value isKindOfClass:[SoapFault class]]) 
    {
    NSLog(@"%@", value);
    return;
    }               
    NSMutableArray* result = (NSMutableArray*)value;
    NSMutableArray *documentList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    self.myDocList = [[NSMutableArray array] init];
    for (int i = 0; i < [result count]; i++)
    {
       EDVDocument *docObj = [[EDVDocument alloc]init];
       docObj = [result objectAtIndex:i];
       [documentList addObject:[docObj docName]];        
    }
    self.myDocList = documentList;
    [docTable reloadData];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{  
   [super viewDidUnload];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
return YES;
}
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
  return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    int cnt = [self.myDocList count];
    NSLog(@"ABC=%@",cnt);
    return [self.myDocList count];
    //return 1;
 }

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   DocumentCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"DocumentCell"];
   if (cell == nil)
   {
      cell = [[[DocumentCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"DocumentCell"] autorelease];
   }
   NSLog(@"cell text=%@",[self.myDocList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);
   cell.lblDocName.text = [self.myDocList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   return cell;
}
```

I am using storyboard.I have hooked the "docTable",set the datasource and the delegate for "docTable".The problem is,the service is called after the call to **"numberOfRowsInSection"**.So,**'return [self.myDocList count]'** is 0.I have put **[docTable reloadData]** in **viewWillAppear** as well as in the service handler,that is,**"getDocsByCatIdHandler"**.But it isn't getting reloaded,as expected.Is there anything else I can try? **EDIT**:- This a Master-Detail application.I have used the same code for loading data in the "MasterViewController" UITableViewController and it works.When the user selects a cell in this table,I need to populate data in the second tableview by calling the WCF service.The second tableview isn't displaying data.

Comment: have you tried the NSNotificationCenter for reloading the table ?

Comment: Can you put any notification in WCF service at the end of the whole process of receiving the data ?

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks good which leads me to believe you are not getting the results from the webservice you are expecting.

One small thing first thats not your problem. If result is in fact an array and there is an object in it, you shouldnt need to alloc a new EDVDocument.

```
EDVDocument *docObj = [result objectAtIndex:i];
```

Can you log the (id)value parameter to see what we're working with?

```
NSLog(@"%@", value);
```

If value is not an array, the cast wont complain, it will just work by not working. However, if it is an array you may be finding trouble with assigning your property (granted I dont know how its declared) to a local array. You can use the following function to create a new array with the elements of your temporary array;

```
self.myDocList = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:documentList];
[docTable reloadData];
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: :-Well,the NSLog of "value" is an array.So,that isn't an issue.The only problem is the table not getting reloaded.I have tried your suggestions,but they work the same as my code does.The only issue i have is with reloading the table.The call to web service works fine and it returns an array.Anything else i should be looking at?

Comment: @from.NetToiOS I'm not sure, first try removing the reloadData in viewWillLoad and keep an eye on your console. You should see `ABC=cnt` twice, the first time `ABC=0` and another after the service handler with `[result count]`. How many times do you see it?

Comment: "ABC" only appears once.So,though I am calling the [docTable reloadData],the "numberOfRowsInSection" is called once.The sequence of the method call is:(1)viewDidLoad(2)viewWillAppear(3)numberOfSectionsInTableView(4)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation(5)numberOfSectionsInTableView(6)numberOfRowsInSection(7)call to the web service. Even though I am "reloading" thetable after the web service call,the "numberOfRowsInSection" isn't getting called.

Comment: Dunno what to tell you, reloadData should cause the delegate methods to be called again. If they arent, then your tableView is getting set to nil or your datasource is getting reassigned. Are you using a storyboard or a nib? perhaps that is where datasource/delegate is being set and `docTable` is not connected as an outlet?

Comment: I am using a storyboard and I have hooked the docTable as the outlet.i have also set the datasource and delegate outlets in the storyboard.The .h file looks like this :                        `#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface DocumentViewController : UITableViewController
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UITableView *docTable;
@end` Do i have to put <UItableviewdatasource,uitableviewdelegate> in the .h file? Also,how to check if the tableview is set to nil or the datasource is getting reassigned? Sorry if i sound noobish,i am new to iPhone development

Comment: :-I can send you the code if you would like to have a look at it.Pls help me with this....i am stuck on this since the last 2 days.I am not able to figure out whats wrong with the code?

Comment: For those who stumble upon this while searching for the solution.The solution is simple,I replaced `[docTable reloadData];` with `[self.tableView reloadData];` and it did the trick.I am new to iPhone development,so I don't really understand the difference between `[docTable reloadData]` and `[self.tableView reloadData]` but it works and thats what I wanted :)

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue when i have a async webService call. I was using a private Library to call webservice so my control goes to the library and after the response comes a method in Appdelegate is set as handler. So what you need to do is before calling the Webservice save the state of tableview in a shared variable and after you have received response set it back to tableView and then call the reload method. Something like below:

```
SharedView.tblView = self.tableView; 
[webservice Call];

After Response:
 self.tableView = SharedView.tblView;
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Hope This Helps.